# Add to state from Redux middleware

Tags: javascript, redux

I've created a redux middleware used for calling my API.

For better debugging I've also implemented `status` for each of the objects in my state.

Now I have to do this in every case of all reducers:

```
    case SET_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        workspaces: action.response.data.workspaces,
        status: action.status, <--
      }
```

Which is pretty repetetive. Is there any way I can change the state (at the correct place) each time automatically?

I do have access to the action type, maybe I could use that somehow?